# Is there a way to get autocomplete for .proto JavaScript generated code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, autocomplete, proto

I've written a simple .proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Event {
  optional string name = 1;
}
```

I've downloaded the protoc linux compiler (protoc-3.19.3-linux-x86_64.zip) and installed it in my local machine outside of the project's folder.

Then I installed the core runtime dependency with

> $ npm i google-protobuf

My package.json shows:

```
"google-protobuf": "^3.19.3",
```

I then ran this line to generate the JS code from the .proto file

> $ protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:. protos/event.proto

It outputs some generated code that I can import with

```
const Schema = require("./protos/event_pb");
```

by inspecting Schema.Event I can see that my prop .name is in there, but I can't get any autocomplete going. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you generating javascript or typescript?

Comment: javascript but I usually get autocomplete in VScode for js imports. The rest of the project is in typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there are some well-maintained npm packages that handle these things.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs
or
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-proto

Answer (score 0):

Add this code at the end of generated file `*_pb.js`

```
...
goog.object.extend(exports, proto);

// fix auto completion
module.exports = exports;
```

Work for me in Intellji editor.